# Which Project Template should I use to create a Web Service for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure, xamarin

I want to create a Rest Web Service and deploy it to Azure, so that I can consume it with Xamarin Forms PCL.

There are REST, SOAP and WCF Web Services, and as far as I know WCF Web services include at least REST. So this kind of confuses me. I have been reading and it seems that WP8.1 can't consume WCF?

If the answer is ASP.net template to create a web service, then which one? And do I need to have a "web page" available in order to have a web service available?

In the end, how should I deploy it to Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REST API is perhaps the best way to expose a backend to a mobile app.  Use the ASP.NET project template and check the Web API checkbox.  Here's a Getting Started documentation page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

When you create your project, there's an option to host your project in Azure.  Publishing is easy, right-click on the project and select Publish.

[image]

You don't need to have a "web page" in order to have a web service available.